# CruiseControl, Specflow HTML report file merge task sometimes failing

Tags: xml, cruisecontrol.net, specflow, cruisecontrol

I am trying to have the Specflow html report for my cruise control integration test run but I am encountering a strange issue. When all the tests pass and the build is successful then the specflow html report can be viewed in cruise control dashboard as expected. However if the build fails (ie if any of the specflow scenarios don't pass) then when I try to view the html report cruise control outputs "Unable to find file."

This is the relevant portion of my ccnet.config:

```
   <publishers>
   <exec>
    <executable>(path)specflow.exe </executable>
    <baseDirectory>(path)</baseDirectory>
    <buildArgs> nunitexecutionreport (path)/(file) 
    /xmlTestResult:(path)\TestResults\testReport_nunit.xml 
    /out:(path)\testReport.html </buildArgs>
    <successExitCodes>0</successExitCodes>
  </exec>
  <merge>
    <files>
      <file>(path)\TestResults\testReport.xml</file>
      <file action="Copy">(path)\TestResults\testReport.html</file>
      <file>(path)\TestResults\codeCoverage.xml</file>
    </files>
  </merge>
```

Comment: If you look at the raw xml build log what does it show? Is "unable to find file" part of a message within the build log?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything about the report in the build log

Comment: Just to confirm, the build log xml, doesn't contain the text "Unable to find file"?

Comment: That is correct. I did a CTRL+F on the build log and that text is not there. When I go to view the Specflow report that text appers in the iframe. And once again, if the build is successful the report works fine.

Comment: Ok, reason for asking is that this text must be coming from specflow, maybe a bug when some content isn't in the build log. I wondered whether it was during the merge/publish phase that embedded this content in the log.

Comment: Should it be `<file action="Copy">(path)\testReport.html</file>`?

Comment: No sorry the build argument that I listed should have included the TestResults folder. The path is consistent from the file action and the specflow command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What I did is :

- Use the incrementOnFailure option in my project labeller (so that I have a different artifact directory for every build, succeeded or failed)
- The url /build/log20141003022201.xml/RetrieveBuildFile.aspx?file=TestResult.html did not work yet but the url RetrieveBuildFile.aspx?file=../{$buildNb}/TestResult.html worked. I have an old version of ccnet (1.5), it might work with newer versions.
- I wrote a custom xsl to link to this very url. Here is the main code

```
<xsl:if test="contains(//cruisecontrol/parameters/parameter[@name='$CCNetProject']/@value,'Specflow')">
    <!-- hack to have the good path to TestResult.html -->
    <xsl:variable name="buildNb" select="//cruisecontrol/parameters/parameter[@name='$CCNetLabel']/@value" />
    <div style="text-align:right; margin:5px; width:100%;">
      <a href="RetrieveBuildFile.aspx?file=../{$buildNb}/TestResult.html" target="_blank">View this report in its own window</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <iframe src="RetrieveBuildFile.aspx?file=../{$buildNb}/TestResult.html" border="1" width="100%" height="1000"></iframe>
    </div>
    <!-- /hack-->
</xsl:if>
```

EDIT : I just installed the 1.8.5 version and the url /build/log20141003022201.xml/RetrieveBuildFile.aspx?file=TestResult.html works well. So I change my xsl to the following

```
<xsl:if test="contains(//cruisecontrol/parameters/parameter[@name='$CCNetProject']/@value,'Specflow')">
    <div style="text-align:right; margin:5px; width:100%;">
      <a href="RetrieveBuildFile.aspx?file=TestResult.html" target="_blank">View this report in its own window</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <iframe src="RetrieveBuildFile.aspx?file=TestResult.html" border="1" width="100%" height="1000"></iframe>
    </div>
</xsl:if>
```